# Saving in SFTP like its a normal folder

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp

So I was using sublime-text 2 to modify some php files held on a remote server. I used `nautilus sftp://... address to server` to open up the folder then clicked on the files and pressed open with sublime text. Whenever I did this it automatically saved the changes on the server. For various annoying reasons I had to restore the machine to factory settings. Now whenever I try to open up the files in the way I use to be able to it just opens a blank file titled sftp in my `/user/dev` directory. Is there anything I need to do to get it back to the way it used to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure anyone else has ever experienced this behavior but I never replicated the nautilus effect that I had originally. The best alternative I found was sublime sftp.

Installed by sublime package control:

https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

Then install sublime sftp:

http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp

I was a student coding in php for a class so I was only using it temporarily and never paid for the license. Probably should do that if you are gonna be using it long term.